# how can I scroll tableView section 2 only after scroll section 1 swift

Tags: swift, scroll, tableview

I have 3 sections in my tableView. after scrolling the first section then I want to scroll only the third section.

Comment: You need to elaborate this question.

Comment: I have 3 sections in my tableView, and 10 row in the third section others have only 1. when I scroll to up and the first section is invisible then I can only scroll the third section. the second section doesn't scroll to top. only third section scroll to top